# Call C# function from Javascript to be redirected to another page

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Actually, I've a login page to connect with facebook. When I click on the facebook button, I would like to redirect user to another page of my application.

I use the following technologies : ASP.NET MVC, C#, Javascript(JQuery), JQuery Mobile

Index.cshtml of Login controller :

```
<head>
  <script>
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {

        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            // Logged into your app and Facebook.
            FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                var faceID = response.id;
                $("#redirectLink").attr("href", "/Home/Index?id=" + faceID);
                console.log($("#redirectLink").attr("href"));
                $("#redirectLink").trigger("click");
            });

        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        } else {
        }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);

        });
    }

  </script>
</head>

<body>
   <div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
     FB.init({
        cookie: true,
        appId: '******',
        xfbml: true,
        status: true, //check login status
        version: 'v2.0'
     });
    };

    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;

        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js";
        js.async = true;
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    setTimeout(function () {
        // login();
    }, 2000);
  </script>

  <div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="ui-content">
        <fb:login-button id="facebookBtn" size="large"
             onlogin="checkLoginState();">Login with Facebook
        </fb:login-button>
        <a id="redirectLink" style="display:none;" data-ajax="false" href="#" />
     </div>
  </div>
```

Home.cs :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index(long id)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

A part of my Home.cshtml that it doesn't contain any javascript :

```
<head>
  @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/ScriptsJQuery")

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
 <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="panel" id="userMenu" data-position="left" data-display="push" data-theme="g">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Menu</li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/Home">Accueil</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/CheckFridge">Mes ingr&eacute;dients</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/AddRecipe">Ajouter une recette</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="#">D&eacute;connexion</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="/MyRecipes">Mes recettes</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="#">Partager</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="header">
        <a id="menuBtn" href="#userMenu" style="position:absolute;"></a>
        <ul id="listMenu" style="display:none;" data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">@Session["user"]</a></li>
            <li><a data-ajax="false" href="@Url.Action("Disconnect","Login")">Deconnexion</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div data-role="ui-content">
        <a data-role="button" href="@Url.Action("Index","CheckFridge")" data-theme="c" data-ajax="false" id="checkFridgeBtn">Check mon frigo</a>
        <a data-role="button" data-theme="c" id="classicSearch">Recherche classique</a>
    </div>

 </div>
</body>
```

The problem is with the following tag in the index.cshtml of  the login controller :

If I do data-ajax="true" and that I run the debugger, I notice that it goes to the Index method of the Home controller but then, when it goes to the view "index.cshtml" of the Home controller, it executes the two first lines(@Styles.Render("~/Content/css"),@Scripts.Render("~/ScriptsJQuery")) and then, it doesn't execute the rest of the html document.

If  I do data-ajax="false", It doesn't go the Home controller and so, it doesn't execute the view 'index.cshtml' of the Home Controller.

Do you have a solution ?

Thank you

Comment: MVC already has support for external login providers, including Facebook. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: For MVC 4 see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/security/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc. For MVC 5 see: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on